# next js запрос уходит дважды

Tags: nextjs

у меня есть такой код

```
export const formJobsUrl = (
  sinceDate,
  currentPage,
  comment,
  authorName,
  instrument,
  userEmal
) =>
  `api/v2/jobs?since=${sinceDate}&page=${currentPage}${
    comment && `&search=${comment}`
  }${makeFilterUserStr(authorName, userEmal)}${
    instrument?.configName === 'all' || !instrument?.configName
      ? ''
      : `&filter_tool=${instrument?.configName}`
  }`.trim();


  const { data: jobsData, trigger: jobsTrigger } = useSWRMutation(
    formJobsUrl(
      sinceDate,
      currentPage,
      comment,
      authorName,
      instrument,
      userData.profile.email
    ),
    updateFetcher
  );

  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    jobsTrigger(tillDate);
  }, 1000);

  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    },
    [jobsTrigger, tillDate, timeoutId]
  );
```

в коде есть еще парочка вызовов jobsTrigger(tillDate), но эти вызовы либо в фунцкии, либо в каком-то эффекте, у которого есть зависимости, да и суть в том, что в setTimeout я ставлю console.log и консоль срабатывает дважды, каждую секунду и это вроде не нормально
я слышал про strict mode, но я никак не пойму как его выключить и почему-то мне кажется дело не в нем, да еще нужно добавить, что это не реакт, а next js, подскажите как отключить повторный запрос, точнее даже повторный setTimeout, то есть setTimeout сейчас срабатывает 2 раза каждую секунду или подскажите как аргументировать и качать права в духе, что так оно и должно быть из-за стрикт мода?)